# How do I load the new Amazon AWS for PHP on a Windows platform?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, installation

I had been using the PHP library up to version 1.6.2 for Amazon AWS. It was great and just worked. Then they rebuilt it and brought out Version 2.

I just want install the latest version without any programs like Composer and others... I have the ZIP file downloaded and copied to a folder `http://localhost/aws/`

How do I access the files and use them? I have tried numerous examples and nothing works. I would prefer to use the latest version and not go back to the old version which is over a year old.

I created the following file in the root of the aws folder:

```
<?php
$config = array();
$config['key'] = 'MYPUBLICKEY';
$config['secret'] = 'MY SECRET KEY';
$config['region'] = 'us-east-1';
$ec2Client = \aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);

$result = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances();

echo "Number of running instances: " . countInstances($result);
?>
```

I don't get a result. It seems to stop at the line $ec2Client =... What should the directory structure be?

Comment: if it stops there and you get no output, then your display_errors/error_reporting settings are disabled, and should be turned on. they should never be off when you're developing or debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the AWS SDK for PHP is fairly comprehensive, especially for basic usage. I would start with the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html), which should provide the information you need. With regards to your particular example, you need to correct a few things:

```
<?php

// Require the autoloader, which is included in the zip
require '/path/to/aws-autoloader.php'; 

$config = array();
$config['key'] = 'MYPUBLICKEY';
$config['secret'] = 'MY SECRET KEY';
$config['region'] = 'us-east-1';
// Please consider using a credential file instead of hard-coding credentials
// See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html#credential-profiles

// Note: Classes and Namespaces are case-sensitive with the autoloader
// (i.e., "Aws", instead of "aws")
$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);

$result = $ec2Client->describeInstances();

// SDKv2 has a cool getPath function which makes it easy to traverse results
$instanceCount = count($result->getPath('Reservations/*/Instances');
echo "Number of running instances: " . $instanceCount
```

Comment: No, the Getting Started Guide is not helpful. It assumes you know a lot about many technologies. I'm used to AWS PHP 1.6.2. Your example above is a copy of the code from the site. It has a require aws-autoloader.php but there is no autoloader code in any download I did. The ZIP file was supposed to be complete... As I said I don't want to have to load any other software to use the API. I can select the modules that I want to use and include them.  Sorry, but the reply above doesn't help me at all, especially after reading through all the documentation

Comment: Where did you get the zip file? The [installation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html#installing-via-zip) of the user guide has the link to the zip.